# Docusign API - Update from email and identity

Tags: docusignapi

I would like to change the sender (from : ...) email and identity for each envelope with the api in php.
Without change the account user email and identity.
Is it possible ?

If it's not possible, i have also try with creating a new admin user and change the user_id in the api client. But i can't get the access token only changing the user id. Is it normal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "From" field is entirely dependant on the user that makes the API call to send the envelope - the only way to control it is to change the user that is authenticating and sending the API call.